# Poll: How many SharePoint Web apps are there in your farm?

Tags: infrastructure, web, web-application

I am interested to know how many Web apps people have deployed in their SharePoint farms.

If you are a consultant then an average figure would be helpful based on client installations you have worked with.

Please state whether the farm is MOSS or 2010.

Answer (score 2):

MOSS 2007, ~100,000 users, approx 20 web apps. 1 for each geographic location + CA + MySites (each with their own content DB)

Comment: Now that's a farm with chest hair.

Comment: It's the largest (by far) of several we run.

Answer (score 1):

3 (external, internal and my sites) + CA - SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

4 as follows in Office Sharepoint Server 2007:

- intranet - this is basically the web
  application that was used as the
  portal in Sharepoint 2003 then
  migrated to SP2007
- teams - team sites
- mysites
- sandbox - a web application I set up to allow various people around the organisation to experiment with Sharepoint features without messing up their own individual sites.

Note - I think if I was setting this up now, I wouldn't have separate web applications for the intranet and team sites. Rather I would do this with site collections, with an organisational site collection, then a site collection for each department in the org, and subsites for each team.

Answer (score 0):

10 + CA - SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

5 + CA SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

2 + CA MOSS 2007 Enterprise at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

5 + CA MOSS 2007

Answer (score 0):

My average would be about 5 + CA in both versions (2010 & 2007)

Answer (score 0):

The better question here might be "how do you purpose your web applications when you create them?" There really should be no hard limit as to how many web apps are created per farm.  However I've seen many a person treat web applications as site collections and things get really out of hand when you do that...

My policies are this:

1) If a group of sites have an entirely different security policy (Forms Vs. Windows Authentication, Internal vs. External Access, etc.) you're talking a new Web Application

2) Entirely different branding is usually a reason for a new web application (to the point of where it's a whole new logo and webpage)

I usually try and discourage people from getting a new web application for URL vanity reasons or "but we want our-department.company.com instead of company.com/thisdepartment"  but have been known to relent there.  Some people have firmer governance in place that prohibits this sort of thing...

Comment: I fundamentally disagree this. Creating Web apps is an infrastructure piece that should normally only need to be carried out during initial farm setup. Whilst the security point may be valid, branding and vanity URLs are not reasons for a new Web app. I've written a blog on this over at http://www.benjaminathawes.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18 if you are interested.

Comment: Tend to agree, I guess I should state that the different branding is typically driven by a different company or different major division within the company.  This is usually when I see a move to a new web application.  I like to discourage this when possible, but the reality has been a different matter.

Comment: What's the reason for creating a new Web app? If this is for a vanity URL, have you tried using host-named site collections?

Answer (score 0):

- 1 - Collaboration (OOTB strict)
- 10 - Custom Application
- 2 - Adv Collab (SharePoint Designer customization , nintex..etc)